# ImageView Scaling Issues - Android

Tags: android, imageview, scale

I have scaled an image using the setScaleX and setScaleY methods and the images have scaled down properly but the ImageViews position does not update.

It is in a relative layout and I have a margin set at 50 - but the scaled image has not updated its position so the margin is at 50.

I am doing this dynamically using Java code, any help?

Comment: How many times are you going to ask this question?  I suggest that you read the documentation for the views you are trying to use and follow some tutorials.  To answer the question, of course the margins won't change unless you change them.  Why do you expect scaling them to also move them?

Comment: Im not expecting the margins to change, Im expecting the view to update its position and keep the margin at 50, which it isnt

Comment: If the margin hasn't changed, and you're using a relative layout which will have alignment (either default or according to your settings) then it won't move.  Why would it?  You've scaled it.  Without code and the layout, impossible to suggest a solution but please take the advice.  Read the documentation for relative layout and understand the use of margin, alignments and sizing.  There are plenty of tutorials out there.

Comment: hey, @AllanMacmillan, i think you encountered the same case as I faced as well... please check this out, hope you could help me out too... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32023108/android-how-to-scaley-to-based-on-other-objects-position